# Image confidence value in python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing

So, I know there are ways to [label images](https://www.clickworker.com/crowdsourcing-glossary/image-labeling/) using TensorFlow or other library, but I want to get a confidence value of how likely it thinks a specific image is of a label.

Let's say I have a folder called `dataset/` with 1000 images of apples in it. Now, I have a new image, called `maybe_an_apple.png`:

[image]

When I run my magic python script, I expect there to be a value (ranging from 0-1), indicating how likely `maybe_an_apple.png` is an image of an apple. In this case, I expect the value to be high (above 0.5), indicating that `maybe_an_apple.png` is in fact an apple.

How can I achieve this using python?

Thanks in advance, 
Robin

Comment: All image classification models will give you an associated confidence score with their prediction, because internally the output of the model is one confidence score per output class, and the model picks the highest confidence label as the output.

Comment: If you have a dataset of sufficient size, let's say 1000 images of apples (correctly labeled), then you can train a simple classifier using Tensorflow in python to get new label. There are also a number of public available datasets where you can find more similar classes to improve your model. Clustering algorithms can also work in this case. One another option could be to calculate cosine similarity between input image and already available images. The result will be between 0-1.

Comment: An interesting read: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/image-similarity-model-6b89a22e2f1a